# Why does the ouptut of wc -l differ if executed in backticks?

Tags: bash, wc

I just encountered that the output of wc -l differs when called directly or enclosed in backticks. For example:

```
pgrep bash | wc -l
```

would output 1, as there is one bash process running. But enclosing this command in backticks

```
echo `pgrep bash | wc -l`
```

would output 2. I first thought, the backticks would open a new bash process, but

```
echo `pgrep bash`
```

does only find the same one process as above. The same is when enclosing the command in $():

```
echo $(pgrep bash | wc -l)
```

This will also output 2. Does somebody know why that is so?

Comment: I guess it's the pipe in the backticks, because `echo "pgrep bash | cat"` (just imagine the double quotes being backticks :)) also returns 2 PIDs, but putting 2 or more pipes in the command didn't change the number of PIDs returned.

Comment: @cularis: You should post this as an answer (I was just about to).

Comment: @Manny: No, that's not it.  `echo \`pgrep bash\`` prints the PIDs on one line, but in `echo \`pgrep bash | wc -l\`` the `wc` command sees one PID per line.  (Yes, you can escape backticks with backslashes!)

Comment: @Keith I have no documentation/other support for my theory, it was just a quick test. Feel free to write an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

@cularis should really get the credit for this, since he posted it as a comment (just) before I had a chance to post it as an answer.

Apparently

```
pgrep bash | wc -l
```

doesn't create a new bash process; it's able to invoke `pgrep bash` and `wc -l` from the original bash process directly.

But

```
echo `pgrep bash | wc -l`
```

*does* create a new bash process because of the pipe (a new process is the easiest way to manage all the I/O redirection and process management needed for the `|` nested within backticks).  So in this case, `pgrep bash` sees the newly created bash process used to handle the pipe, in addition to the original (interactive/) process used to execute the command.

Try

```
pgrep bash
```

and

```
echo `pgrep bash | cat`
```

In a very quick look at the bash documentation (`info bash`, section 3.5.4,  Command Substitution) I don't see anything that says when it creates a new process and when it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys. I actually found a better solution. Instead of using wc -l I should have just use the -c argument, which does only print the count of matching processes. Well, RTFM again. ;-)